# Creating a frame in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering, is it possible to create a frame such as a JFrame in Batch? If so I'd really like to know how so that the program I am writing will look better. I'm aware that JFrame is for java, I was giving that as an example, but is it really possible to create something that resembles a JFrame in Batch??

Comment: you have another answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you'll find this answer more satisfying:

```
mshta "about:<button type='button' onclick='alert("clckd!")'>clck here</button>"
```

~

```
rem bat file version
mshta "about:<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg'>"
```

~

```
rem paste in command prompt
mshta "about:<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg'>"
```

You can create [HTA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx) directly from command line / bat file. Though it has a lot of limitations it can be useful.

**EDIT**

more examples(save them as `.bat` files):

1.Submit password:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /*JScript comment
@echo off
mshta "about:<body onload='prepare()'><script language='javascript' src='file://%~dpnxf0'></script><input type='password' name='pass' size='15'></input><hr><button onclick='pipePass()'>Submit</button><body>" |findstr "^"
exit /b 0

**/

function prepare(){
    //document.write("<input type='password' name='pass' size='15'></input><hr><button onclick='pipePass()'>Submit</button>");
}

function pipePass() {
    //alert("blabla");
      var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
      var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
      close(fso.Write(pass));

}
```

2.Select a file

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /*JScript comment
@echo off
mshta "about:<body onload='prepare()'><script language='javascript' src='file://%~dpnxf0'></script><input type='file' name='file' size='30'></input><hr><button onclick='pipeFile()'>Submit</button><body>" |findstr "^"
exit /b 0

**/

function prepare(){

}

function pipeFile() {

      var file=document.getElementById('file').value;
      var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
      close(fso.Write(file));

}
```

3.Choose button:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end/*JScript comment
@echo off
mshta "about:<title>chooser</title><body onload='prepare()'><script language='javascript' src='file://%~dpnxf0'></script><span id='container'>buttons:</span></body>" |findstr "^"
exit /b 0

**/

function clckd(a){
     // alert(a);
    var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
     ;
    close(fso.Write(a));
}

function prepare(){
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element1.setAttribute("value", "yes");
    // this will not work on IE or MSHTA
    //element1.setAttribute("onclick", "clckd('yep');");
    element1.onclick= function() {clckd('yep');};

    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element2.setAttribute("value", "no");
    // this will not work on IE or MSHTA
    //element2.setAttribute("onclick", "clckd('nope');");
    element2.onclick= function() {clckd('nope');};


    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(element1);
    container.appendChild(element2);

    //alert(document.getElementById('container').innerHTML);    
}
```

Comment: So, this will create something like a jframe?

Comment: With this you can create html forms. Curently im working on few more complex examples that ill post here

Comment: Okay, it worked :) but how do I change the title? I can't seem to find where to do that

Comment: you cant. the title is part of the "hack" that allows you to call mshta from command line.

Comment: @benimen16 check my new posted example

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no built-in Windows facilities for making arbitrary GUI widgets from batch files.