# batch file - pop up with optional arguments

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arguments

First time poster.
I use a program called PDW. It scans pager frequencies and displays pager messages on the screen.
One of the functions is that it can run a batch or COM file when it pics up a message to a specific pager.
It also has the function to be able to pass through "optional arguments" to the batch or COM file.
.
This is what it says in the help document of the program;

> Command file
>   The command file lets you run an external program file (with optional arguments) when 
>   you receive a filter match and the filter has the “Enable filter command file” enabled.
>   This program file can be any executable file or a “.BAT” or “.COM” file.
>   “Browse” lets you browse for a filename, or you can just type in a filename directly.
>   In the “arguments” control you can enter the arguments to be passed to the command 
>   file.
>   These can be anything you like or any of these special character sequences :
>    %1 Address
>    %2 Time
>    %3 Date
>    %4 Mode
>    %5 Type
>    %6 Bitrate
>    %7 Message
>    %8 Label
>   For example : “%1” “%2” “%3” “%7” will expand to something like :
>   1234567 15:21:44 01-02-10 This is a TEST message

Currently I have the following batch file set up (found on stackoverflow), which creates a popup but does not display the optional arguments...

```
>@echo off  
echo code=Msgbox(" ALERT!", vbYesNo, "TRIGGER ALERT") > "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"  
echo WScript.Quit code >> "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"  
cscript /nologo "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"  
if %errorlevel%==6 call :ok_tag  
if %errorlevel%==7 call :cancel_tag  
echo Done!  
exit /b 1  
:ok_tag  
echo You pressed Yes!  
exit /b  
:cancel_tag  
echo You pressed No!  
exit /b
```

What I want to do, is have a file that not only creates a pop up on my screen, but also can receive these optional arguments from the program (Specifically %1 Address, %2 Time, %3 Date, and %7 Message).
So can anyone help me with a code that will do what I want?

Comment: you can check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120400/creating-a-frame-in-batch/23126756?noredirect=1#comment35389289_23126756  - you can create an html form with mshta/jscript (this will take me some time to create..)

Comment: Probably it will be easier to work directly with HTA application.

Answer (score 1):

This change should give you extra info in the popup

```
 echo code=Msgbox(" %~1 - %~2 - %~3 - %~7 ", vbYesNo, "TRIGGER ALERT") > "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"
```

Comment: I think the OP wants more buttons.And to check pressed buttons from errorlevel

Comment: Here's info about errorlevels and buttons http://forums.mydigitallife.info/archive/index.php/t-24558.html (tough the errorlevel is always 0 with me)